# Open Source Chromium/Chrome extension for translating text selections on right-click

Tags: chrome, translation, dictionary

I am looking for a Chromium/Chrome extension that offers translation for text-selections in the right-click context menu. It should be Open Source and support at least english-english (dictionary) or english-german (translation).

Short: I'm looking for a Chrome alternative to [gtranslate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gtranslate/)

Comment: The [Right Click Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/right-click-translate/piojkjkndneggfaibepkmabjnkjlhlmk?hl=en) Chrome extension shows the translations in a new tab. Is this the tool you need?

Comment: It has been a while.. I'm on Firefox now, but please write an answer, it might be helpful for others. :-)